# Java What is the best way to match Strings?

Tags: java, search, grouping, categories

I have several Lists of Strings. Each list represents a category. I am trying to find which category a specific string is in. I could only think of two ways to do this:

1. Iterate through categories and return the first category that contains it.
2. Create a running hashmap of strings and their categories.

Which one is faster/more efficient or is there a better way than the methods listed above to find which category the string is in?

Comment: why don't you benchmark those 2?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You have to give an example and/or explain what determines a String to be in a specific category.

Comment: I juse use the word category for a list. A set of strings is in a list.

Comment: @ZachSugano Use a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) if you're concerned about performance... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking up something in a hash map is constant time (amortized) whereas iterating through every list is m*n time, where m is the list length and n is the number of lists. Go with the hash map, definitely.

Alternatively, make every string an object that contains the category.

Comment: I like your second suggestion -- make your data smarter, that's the OOPs way. Note that the first suggestion comes with a cost since nothing is free, and that cost is the memory required to create and fill the HashMap.

Comment: actually amortized lookup time means "over worse case scenario", in which the operation is O(N) where N is the number of keys in the map.  In worse case, all values end up in the same bucket, and thus a linear search would be performed on a large bucket to the find the element with that key, thus O(N).  However, in practice, it's usually much quicker than that, but it depends on the distribution of key hashes in the map.    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis

Answer (score 0):

> I have several Lists of Strings. Each list represents a category. I am
>   trying to find which category a specific string is in. I could only
>   think of two ways to do this:

The way this question is posed, makes no sense to me.
If each list represents a category and a `String` ends up in a *specific* list (and you are trying to figure out which) then you already must have a way to map a `String` to a category and therefore a List so you should be able to use that mapping in reverse to find which List is a candidate to `contain` the `String` as a member.
If you don't have such a mapping then this means that each `String` is randomly put on a list but then the list can not represent a category as you mention in you OP.

**Update:**
From your comment it seems that you don't have category of lists but you are storing `Players` and trying to retrieve them using a specific property. Seems to me that you should be using a `HashMap` instead of `List`s in the first place

Comment: Any of the lists could contain any of the strings. I am trying to search for which clan a player is in specifically. I can place the string in, but I can't just backtrace it to figure out which list its in unless I create some sort of "EnhancedString"